# How to modify binding-path at WPF application runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the binding path `SomeProperty` to another **at runtime**. And the PropertyName can be **any string** ,so I can't set it before it running. how to do this?

I tried "FindName" method to find **tb1** but it's not work.

Partical code :

```xml
<ListBox>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the lack of context, let's try to establish one.

Assuming your ListBox is binding to a `Person` list with `FirstName` and `LastName` property, initial binding would be `FirstName` and you want to change it to `LastName` during runtime when clicking on a button.

This is how you can achieve it.

View

```
<ListBox Name="LstBx" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button Click="Button_Click" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Change Binding"/>
```

CodeBehind

```
public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; } = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { FirstName = "ABC", LastName = "123" },
    new Person { FirstName = "DEF", LastName = "456" },
    new Person { FirstName = "GHI", LastName = "789" }
};

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var person in PersonList)
    {
        var listBoxItem = LstBx.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(person);
        var contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(listBoxItem);
        var target = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("tb1", contentPresenter) as TextBox;

        if (target != null)
        {
            var binding = new Binding
            {
                // Remember each ListBoxItem's DataContext is the individual item 
                // in the list, not the list itself.
                Source = person, 
                Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(Person.LastName)),
                // Depends on what you need.
                //Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                //UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
        }
    }
}

// Available from MSDN
private Child FindVisualChild<Child>(DependencyObject obj) where Child : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is Child)
        {
            return (Child)child;
        }
        else
        {
            var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<Child>(child);

            if (childOfChild != null) { return childOfChild; }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're simply looking for "DisplayMemberPath"?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="SomeProperty" />
```

You cannot mix it with DataTemplates but in your example you didn't really need it.

You can create a normal binding for this property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ElementName=DisplayPathText, Path=Text}" />
    <TextBox Name="DisplayPathText" Text="SomeProperty" />
</StackPanel>
```